# What does all this extra data from rsync mean?

Tags: rsync

When I move directories with `rsync`, I get some extra data to the right of the progress bar right after each file has been copied:

```
$ rsync -aP assembly /media/andreas/backup
sending incremental file list
assembly/
assembly/1. East Rutherford - English - Friday AM.mp4
  4,227,174,902 100%   25.38MB/s    0:02:38 (xfr#1, to-chk=6/8)
assembly/2. East Rutherford - English - Friday PM.mp4
  5,196,565,076 100%   25.04MB/s    0:03:17 (xfr#2, to-chk=5/8)
assembly/3. East Rutherford - English - Saturday AM.mp4
    596,565,076  10%   24.70MB/s    0:02:57
```

What do those `xfr` and `to-chk` parts mean?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This, like most things, is explained in `rsync`'s
extremely comprehensive [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rsync.1.html) (emphasis mine):

> When  the  file  transfer  finishes, rsync replaces the progress line
>   with a summary line that looks like this:
>
> ```
>  1,238,099 100%  146.38kB/s    0:00:08  (xfr#5, to-chk=169/396)
> ```
>
> In this example, the file was 1,238,099 bytes long in total, the
>   average rate of transfer for the whole file was 146.38 kilobytes per
>   second over the 8 seconds that it took to complete, **it  was the 5th
>   transfer of a regular file during the current rsync session**, and **there
>   are 169 more files for the receiver to check** (to see if they are
>   up-to-date or not) remaining **out of the 396 total files in the
>   file-list.**

So, in your example, `assembly/2. East Rutherford - English - Friday PM.mp4` was the second file to be transferred, and another 5 of a total of 8 files will need to be checked.

Comment: Doh, I forgot the first rule of Linux: _"When in doubt, check the man pages"_

Comment: Or StackOverflow :P